# Is it not possible to supply a thread facory or name pattern to ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I would like to set name for threads of the ForkJoinPool used by work stealing pool, supplied by

```
ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool(int parallelism)
```

or

```
ExecutorService newWorkStealingPool()
```

So far I could not find a way to set custom names on threads used by this `ExecutorService`, is there a way?

`newWorkStealingPool()` basically supplies a `ForkJoinPool`, but `ForkJoinPool` also doesn't have a public constructor with supplied name pattern.

**update**:
I have now found this constructor of
[`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-boolean-) which takes a thread factory `ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`. But factory should return a `ForkJoinWorkerThread`, which doesn't have a public constructor. So I guess I will have to subclass `ForkJoinWorkerThread`.

Comment: Isn't that just a convenience method? You can make your own ForkJoinPool with a thread factory that does the naming for you.

Comment: Oops, don't know but somehow missed this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-boolean- Yup, as you said that was my thought too but failed to notice mentioned constructor.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This seems to be the minimum required code, reusing the existing default factory:

```
final ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = new ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory() {
  @Override         
  public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
    final ForkJoinWorkerThread worker = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
    worker.setName("my-thread-prefix-name-" + worker.getPoolIndex());
    return worker;
  }
};
        
final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), factory, null, false);
```

Update for later JDK versions:

```
final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
final ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = pool -> {
  final ForkJoinWorkerThread worker = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
  worker.setName("my-thread-prefix-name-" + index.getAndIncrement());
  return worker;
};

final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), factory, null, false);
```

Comment: Looks good except for the fact that `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()` sets the last argument (`async`) to `true`. You should probably do the same.

Comment: Nice catch. In general, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-boolean-) for the async parameter is:

> if true, establishes local first-in-first-out scheduling mode for forked tasks > that are never joined. This mode may be more appropriate than default 
> locally stack-based mode in applications in which worker threads only 
> process event-style asynchronous tasks. For default value, use false.

Comment: I tried an example, and worker.getPoolIndex() always returns zero.

Comment: @k.liakos you are correct. I don't think you can invoke `worker.getPoolIndex()` before the pool has started. In any case, you could create a static `AtomicLong` field and generate IDs using `AtomicLong.getAndIncrement()`.

Comment: @k.liakos @Gili Based on my testing, I think `worker.getPoolIndex()` used to provide an incrementing integer, but doesn't in newer JDK versions. When I ran the example code in this answer under [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/#zulu) JDK *11*, the threads got unique names, but under Azul Zulu JDK *17*, they did not. The suggestion of using an `AtomicLong` is a good one. I wonder if the answer can be updated to reflect this, since JDK 11 is quite old now.

Comment: Updated with  a version working on Java 17. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: We can keep the thread index by```String wname = worker.getName();``` and ```worker.setName("my-thread-prefix-name-" + wname.substring(a.lastIndexOf("-")+1));```

Answer (score 5):

(Answering your update)

The following should allow you full control over the threads produced by your `ForkJoinPool`s. In my case I wanted to be able to do "dangerous" stuff like access system properties. The default implementation uses `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.InnocuousForkJoinWorkerThread` which has a security manager and zero permissions.

```
public class MyForkJoinThreadFactory implements ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
  @Override
  public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
    return new NotSoInnocuousWorkerThread(pool);
  }
}
```

and the worker thread (that now has all the same permissions as the rest of your application is this like this, plus whatever else you wanted....

```
public class NotSoInnocuousWorkerThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread {
  protected NotSoInnocuousWorkerThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
    super(pool);
  }
}
```

And you need to either pass the following property or set it in your code like this:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory", 
                   MyForkJoinThreadFactory.class.getName());
```

Comment: I had already updated the question, method suggested is same as what I had done in the end. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is @Morten Haraldsen's answer ported to Kotlin:

```
val forkJoinPool =
    ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory { pool ->
        ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool).apply {
            name = "my-thread-prefix-name-$poolIndex"
        }
    }.let { factory -> ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), factory, null, true) }
```

Comment: the OP mentioned Java, not Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote explanation. When searching for how to do this in Kotlin this question is near the top of the results so this answer still seems valuable to me.

Comment: And the OP does not mention Java, they ask about ForkJoinPool which is a JVM class usable from Java, Kotlin, Scala, etc.

Comment: there is the Java tag for this question

Comment: There is also a `java.util.concurrent` tag, which is usable from all the JVM languages, like Kotlin. I don't see how having a Kotlin answer for something from the [Java Class Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library), which is available to all JVM languages, is negative in any way.

Comment: let's write the examples for Scala/Groovy/Closure as well then

Comment: @mr.M I think you meant Clojure.