# Is it possible to set the priority of the threads in Stream.parallel()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-threads

If I want to run a Stream in parallel in a background task is it possible to run it in lower priority? And if so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The procedure is as follows:

1. Create a `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` that creates threads with an appropriate priority.
2. Create a `ForkJoinPool` using the above thread factory.
3. Instantiate the parallel stream.
4. Run the stream by submitting it to the `ForkJoinPool`

Something like this:

```
public class MyThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread {
    public MyThread(ForkJoinPool pool, int priority) {
        super(pool);
        setPriority(priority);
    }
}

final int poolSize = ...
final int priority = ...

List<Long> aList = LongStream.rangeClosed(firstNum, lastNum).boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = new ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory() {
    public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
         return new MyThread(pool, priority);
    }
};
/*
ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = pool -> new MyThread(
  pool,
  priority
);
*/

ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(
    poolSize, factory, null, false);
long actualTotal = customThreadPool.submit(
    () -> aList.parallelStream().reduce(0L, Long::sum)).get();
```

(Example code *adapted* from http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool)

Comment: I said "something like" :-)   It needed a `pool` argument.

Comment: It still doesn't compile. I think you have to subclass it.

Comment: This should do it: `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = pool -> new ForkJoinWorkerThread(pool) {{ setPriority(priority); }};`

Comment: Did it a slightly different way ... but it compiles and runs.  The only gotcha is that `submit` throws `InterruptedException` which needs to be handled.

Comment: The second gotcha might be that (unless you're on Java 10) the number of fork join tasks created will be in proportion to the [common pool parallelism](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190974)

Comment: `ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` is (structurally) a functional interface, so factory can be defined as `pool -> new MyThread(pool, priority)`.

Comment: Should be noted that this behavior is an undocumented implementation details, as is the entire use of the Fork/Join pool. There is no guaranty that this works in other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this is like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38026502):

```
public class CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory implements ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {

    private final int threadPriority;

    public CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory(int threadPriority) {
        this.threadPriority = threadPriority;
    }

    @Override           
    public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool)
    {
        final ForkJoinWorkerThread worker = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
        worker.setPriority(threadPriority);
        return worker;
    }
}
```

It allows you to still use a "default" ForkJoinWorkerThread, but you can set priority / name / etc. Use like this:

```
new ForkJoinPool(poolSize, new CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY), null, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline version of the previous answer

```
new ForkJoinPool(parallelism, (pool) -> {
    ForkJoinWorkerThread thread = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
    thread.setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY + 1);
    return thread;
}, null, false);
```